# Firebase retrieves my Double as a String in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, string, swift, firebase, double

So I'm saving a dictionary to my firebase. The dictionary is located in a custom class I made called FoodItem. Here's the lines where I save the dictionary:

```
let favRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("urlhidden")
favRef.setValue(foodItem.toAnyObject())
```

foodItem is a FoodItem object, here's the part of my FoodItem class that implements .toAnyObject()

```
var key: String
var ref: Firebase?
var name: String
var description: String
var minCal: Int
var maxCal: Int
var containsNuts: Bool
var vegetarian: Bool
var price: Double //**NOTE THAT PRICE IS A DOUBLE**

func toAnyObject()->[String:AnyObject]{
    return ["name":self.name,
            "price":self.price,
            "description":self.description,
            "minCal":self.minCal,
            "maxCal":self.maxCal,
            "containsNuts":self.containsNuts,
            "vegetarian":self.vegetarian]
    }
```

So those bits of code combined saves my data to my firebase. Works as it should. But when I retrieve the data, my price variable is a string? I'll explain...

Here's where I retrieve the data:

```
func getCurrentOrder(){
    let uid = ref.authData.uid
    ref = Firebase(url: "urlhidden")
    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        var newItems = [FoodItem]()

        for item in snapshot.children {

            let foodItem = FoodItem(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(foodItem)
        }

        self.order = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

That FoodItem constructor you see with the snapshot takes the data from my firebase and assigns my FoodItem variables to those values in my firebase. Here's that code:

```
init(snapshot: FDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    name = snapshot.value["name"] as! String
    price = snapshot.value["price"] as! Double //**NOTE STILL A DOUBLE**
    description = snapshot.value["description"] as! String
    minCal = snapshot.value["minCal"] as! Int
    maxCal = snapshot.value["maxCal"] as! Int
    containsNuts = snapshot.value["containsNuts"] as! Bool
    vegetarian = snapshot.value["vegetarian"] as! Bool

    ref = snapshot.ref
}
```

However when I run my code, I see that it prints the double as a String
[image: There are quotes around the value of my price]

As you can see, there are clearly quotes around the Double variable "price".
And I get this error:

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0xff0ee0) to 'NSNumber' (0x13ff81c).

With this line of code highlighted in red:

```
price = snapshot.value["price"] as! Double
```

Which is located inside the FoodItem constructor with the snapshot as I posted above.

Any Ideas???

*EDIT: It does the same thing for my int variables. Same error message

Comment: This may not be an issue (currently), but Firebase does not directly support Doubles. It supports 4 object types; NSString, NSNumber, NSDictionary, NSArray. You may want to consider wrapping your double into an NSNumber for storage into Firebase. As it is, you are storing it as a string. It could be an issue if an invalid char is stored or perhaps an empty string instead of 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It never actually saved it as a String. I believe I had that value in there as some old code in which I did save it as a String. I deleted my entries in the database and tried it again and it works just fine. Thank you to those who attempted to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

## 2017 example

It may save someone some typing, here's some completely typical code to observe a simple number value. Let's say it's a fraction called SomeFraction.

As always, **Firebase rocks**  :)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    dev_listenForLiveFraction()
}

var r1: DatabaseReference? = nil
func dev_listenForLiveFraction() {
    
    let p1 = "something/someFractionForExample"
    
    r1 = Database.database().reference(withPath: p1)
    r1!.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        
        let sf: NSNumber = snapshot.value as? NSNumber ?? 0.666
        self.example_handleSomeFraction(sf)
    }
}

func example_handleSomeFraction(_ sf: NSNumber) {
    
    print("the fraction is now \(sf)")
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    clearObservations()
}

private func clearObservations() {
    
    if r1 != nil {
        
        r1?.removeAllObservers()
        r1 = nil
    }
}
```